# while loop to subtract user input from a variable

Tags: c#, loops

Okay, So i have a program that asks for Age, weight, height, and gender. Then it uses if statements to calculate your BMR accordingly, then it uses more if statements to calculate your Daily Calorie Intake. (DCI) After displaying the DCI, I need a WHILE loop where it asks the user to input the amount of calories, and subtracts it from the DCI so it turns into calories remaining. The code I need help with is at the very bottom. I was told I didn't need to make a variable for the number being inputed by the user, but it can be subtracted directly from the DCI so it turns into Calories Remaining.

```
    using System;

namespace Shaft_Lab4
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {

            int weight, height, age, gender;

            double exerciseFactor;
            double DCI = 0;



            Console.Write("Enter your age in years ");
            age = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine ("Enter your weight in pounds ");
            weight = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine ("Enter your height in inches ");
            height = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

            Console.WriteLine ("Gender? Enter male/female (1 for Male, 2 for Female) ");
            gender= Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("To calculate your daily calories allowed, please select your level of exercise activity");

            // exercise intensity levels  

            Console.WriteLine("1. You don't exercise"); // bmr x 1.2
            Console.WriteLine("2. You engage in light exercise one to three days a week"); // bmr x 1.375
            Console.WriteLine("3. You exercise moderately three to five times a week"); // bmr x 1.55
            Console.WriteLine("4. You exercise intensely six to seven days a week"); // bmr x 1.725
            Console.WriteLine("5. you exercise intensely six to seven days a week and have a physically active job"); // bmr x 1.9      

            exerciseFactor = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine ());

            // MALE if statements

            if (gender == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Age: " + age);
                Console.WriteLine ("Height: " + height);
                Console.WriteLine ("Weight: " + weight);
                Console.WriteLine ("Gender: Male");

                double maleBMR = (66 + (6.23 * weight) + (12.7 * height) - (6.8* age));


                Console.WriteLine ("Your BMR is: " + maleBMR);

                if (exerciseFactor == 1) {
                    DCI = maleBMR * 1.2;
                    Console.WriteLine ("Your daily calories allowed is " + DCI);
                }
                if (exerciseFactor == 2) {
                    DCI = maleBMR * 1.375;
                    Console.WriteLine ("Your daily calories allowed is " + DCI);

                }
                if (exerciseFactor == 3) {
                    DCI = maleBMR * 1.55;
                    Console.WriteLine ("Your daily calories allowed is " + DCI);

                }
                if (exerciseFactor == 4) {
                    DCI = maleBMR * 1.725;
                    Console.WriteLine ("Your daily calories allowed is " + DCI);

                }
                if (exerciseFactor == 5) {
                    DCI = maleBMR * 1.9;
                    Console.WriteLine ("Your daily calories allowed is " + DCI);
                }




    // FEMALE if statements

            }


            if (gender == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Age: " + age);
                Console.WriteLine ("Height: " + height);
                Console.WriteLine ("Weight: " + weight);
                Console.WriteLine ("Gender: Female");

                double femaleBMR = (655 + (4.35 * weight) + (4.7 * height) - (4.7 * age));

                Console.WriteLine ("Your BMR is: " + femaleBMR);

                if (exerciseFactor == 1) {
                    DCI = femaleBMR * 1.2;
                    Console.WriteLine ("Your daily calories allowed is " + DCI);
                }
                if (exerciseFactor == 2) {
                    DCI = femaleBMR * 1.375;
                    Console.WriteLine ("Your daily calories allowed is " + DCI);
                }
                if (exerciseFactor == 3) {
                    DCI = femaleBMR * 1.55;
                    Console.WriteLine ("Your daily calories allowed is " + DCI);
                }
                if (exerciseFactor == 4) {
                    DCI = femaleBMR * 1.725;
                    Console.WriteLine ("Your daily calories allowed is " + DCI);
                }
                if (exerciseFactor == 5) {
                    DCI = femaleBMR * 1.9;
                    Console.WriteLine ("Your daily calories allowed is " + DCI);
                }



            }


            //THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP 

            string response = "YES";

            while (response == "YES") {
                Console.WriteLine ("Enter the amount of calories consumed: ");
                Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

                Console.WriteLine ("Do you want to continue? (YES / NO)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main part you need is this:

```
    string response = "YES";
    while (response == "YES")
    {
        caloriesAllowed -= ConsoleReadInteger("Enter the amount of calories consumed: ");
        Console.WriteLine("Your remaining calories allowed is " + caloriesAllowed);
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue? (YES / NO)");
        response = Console.ReadLine().ToUpperInvariant();
    }
```

Here's is your entire code - I've refactored for you so that you can see how to be more efficient with some of your coding:

```
public static int ConsoleReadInteger(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    return Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int age = ConsoleReadInteger("Enter your age in years ");
    int weight = ConsoleReadInteger("Enter your weight in pounds ");
    int height = ConsoleReadInteger("Enter your height in inches ");
    int gender = ConsoleReadInteger("Gender? Enter male/female (1 for Male, 2 for Female) ");

    Console.WriteLine("To calculate your daily calories allowed, please select your level of exercise activity");

    Console.WriteLine("1. You don't exercise"); // bmr x 1.2
    Console.WriteLine("2. You engage in light exercise one to three days a week"); // bmr x 1.375
    Console.WriteLine("3. You exercise moderately three to five times a week"); // bmr x 1.55
    Console.WriteLine("4. You exercise intensely six to seven days a week"); // bmr x 1.725
    Console.WriteLine("5. you exercise intensely six to seven days a week and have a physically active job"); // bmr x 1.9      

    Dictionary<int, double> exerciseFactors = new Dictionary<int, double>()
    {
        { 1, 1.2 }, { 2, 1.375 }, { 3, 1.55 }, { 4, 1.725 }, { 5, 1.9 },
    };

    double exerciseFactor = exerciseFactors[Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())];

    Console.WriteLine("Age: " + age);
    Console.WriteLine("Height: " + height);
    Console.WriteLine("Weight: " + weight);
    Console.WriteLine("Gender: " + (gender == 1 ? "Male" : "Female"));

    double bmr =
        gender == 1
        ? 66 + (6.23 * weight) + (12.7 * height) - (6.8 * age)
        : 655 + (4.35 * weight) + (4.7 * height) - (4.7 * age);

    double caloriesAllowed = bmr * exerciseFactor;

    Console.WriteLine("Your BMR is: " + bmr);
    Console.WriteLine("Your daily calories allowed is " + caloriesAllowed);

    string response = "YES";
    while (response == "YES")
    {
        caloriesAllowed -= ConsoleReadInteger("Enter the amount of calories consumed: ");
        Console.WriteLine("Your remaining calories allowed is " + caloriesAllowed);
        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue? (YES / NO)");
        response = Console.ReadLine().ToUpperInvariant();
    }
}
```

There appears to be an error in your calculation of the BMR. Also, this code has very little error checking, but as long as you enter valid input it should run fine.

Comment: @JasonShaft - `ConsoleReadInteger` is in the code in my answer.

Comment: Yeah, and it doesn't work. No matter, I got the program working, all I needed to do was switch two simple words

Comment: @JasonShaft - Which words?

Answer (score 0):

The `DCI` variable is of type double, so I would like to suggest you to use `double.TryParse` instead for `Convert.ToInt32`. then you have to read the yes or no option from the user, so modify the while like the following:

```
while (response == "YES")
{
   double userInput;
   Console.WriteLine ("Enter the amount of calories consumed: ");
   if( double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput);
   {
       DCI -= value; // performing subtraction
       Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue? (YES / NO)");
       response = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
   }
   else
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
   }
}
```

Comment: updated, now im just confused as to how to make the user input subtract from my DCI variable..

Comment: @JasonShaft: I have updated the answer please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Just loop, read it in and subtract it.

```
string response = "YES";
var value = 0;

    while (response == "YES") {
        Console.WriteLine ("Enter the amount of calories consumed: ");
        Int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value);

        DCI -= value;

        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue? (YES / NO)");
        response = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
    }
```